# upload multiple image in django model from admin panel

Tags: python, django, relationship, models

I have this model.py file but in django admin I can't upload images...how can I upload multiple images for each product?  (1 to many relationship)

**Models.py**

```
TYPE = (('small', 'small'), ('medium', 'medium'), ('big', 'big'))


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Gallery(models.Model):
    image_name = models.TextField()
    image_up = models.ImageField(upload_to='prodotti/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image_name
```

Comment: Use Inlines for your base admin model.

Comment: Can you make an example, please? It is first time I face this case

Comment: Search for `django inlines admin`, it would be good to look in the docs.

Comment: ok I will read it. Is the models file right? I done right the 1 to many association?

Comment: Models are ok. I suggest you move to python3 and don't name your models in plural. Better look also on sort of django style guide.